# SELECT statement returning the column name instead of the VALUE (for that said column)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to parse information in to a SELECT statement using the two column names 'id' and 'easy_high_score' so I can manipulate values of them two columns in my program, but when trying to get the value of the column 'easy_high_score', which should be an integer like 46 or 20, it instead returns a string of ('easy_high_score',).

Even though there is no mention of [('easy_high_score',)] in the table, it still prints this out. In the table, id 1 has the proper values and information i'm trying get but to no avail. I am fairly new to SQLite3.

```
if mode == "Easy":
    mode = 'easy_high_score'

if mode == "Normal":
    mode = "normal_high_score"

if mode == 'Hard':
    mode == "hard_high_score"


incrementor = 1 ##This is used in a for loop but not necessary for this post
c.execute("SELECT ? FROM players WHERE id=?", (mode, incrementor))
allPlayers = c.fetchall()
print(allPlayers)  #This is printing [('easy_high_score',)], when it should be printing an integer.
```

Expected Result: 20 (or an integer which represents the high score for easy mode)

Actual Result: [('easy_high_score',)]

Comment: You can't use parameters for table or column names. They have to be directly present in the statement when it's compiled.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of this is double quotes vs single quotes.

```
'SELECT "COLUMN_NAME" FROM TABLE_NAME' # will give values as desired
"SELECT 'COLUMN_NAME' FROM TABLE_NAME" # will give column name like what you got
```

Answer (score 0):

Column name cannot be specified using a parameter it should be present verbatim in the query. Modify the line that executes the query like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT %s FROM players WHERE id=?" % mode, (incrementor,))
```